# objective-c only clear the badge when app opens

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

Is there any way to clear the badge for an app with out removing the notification from the notification center?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i tried the following but didnt work 

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:-1];

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

in applicationDidBecomeActive